# How could I aggregate all untracked files in one

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to sorucetree, I used to git-tower.

How could I aggregate all untracked files in one.

[image: inline]

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but if you're trying to group all the untracked files into a single line, SourceTree will not do that.